# Java won't replace all strings, because there is text next to the tags (post improved)

Tags: java, regex, replace, formatting, replaceall

I'm working on a program, which formats HTML Code, extracted from a PDF file.
I have a String list, which contains paragraphs and is divided by that.
As the PDF has hyperlinks, I decided to replace them with a foot note number "[1]".
This will be used for citation of sources. I will eventually plan, to put it at the end of a paragraph, or sentence, so you can look up the sources, like you would in a book.

**My Problem**
For some reason not all the hyperlinks are replaced.
The reason is most likely, that there is text directly next to the tag.

```
Hell<a href="http://www.example.com">o old chap!
```

Specifically the "o" part and the "hell" part is blocking the java .replaceAll function, from doing it's job.

**Expected Result**

```
Hello [1] old chap!
```

**EDIT:**
If I would just add space, before and after the URL, it might split some words like "help", into "hel p", which is also not an option.

My code would have to replace the URL tag (without the ) and create no new extra spaces.

This is some of my code, where the problem occures:

```
for (int i = 0; i < EN.length; i++) {
        Pattern pattern_URL = Pattern.compile("<a(.+?)\">", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcher_URL = pattern_URL.matcher(EN[i]); //Checks in the curren Array part.

        if (matcher_URL.find() == true) {
            source_number++;
            String extractedURL = matcher_URL.group(0);
            //System.out.println(extractedURL);
            String extractedURL_fully = extractedURL.replaceAll("href=\"", ""); //Anführungszeichen
            //System.out.println(extractedURL_fully);

            String nobracketURL = extractedURL.replaceAll("\\)", ""); //Remove round brackets from URL

            EN[i] = EN[i].replaceAll("\\)\"", "\""); /*Replace round brackets from URL in Array. (For some reasons there have been href URLs, with an bracket at the end. This was already in the PDF. They were causing massive problems, because it didn't comment them out, so the entire replaceAll command didn't function.)*/
            EN[i] = EN[i].replaceAll(nobracketURL, "[" + source_number + "]"); //Replace URL tags with number and Edgy brackets
        }
        else{
            //System.out.println("FALSE: " + "[" + i + "]");

        }



    }
```

The whole idea of this is, that it loops through the array and replaces all the URLs, including it's starting tag <a until the end of the starting tag "> (which can also be seen in the pattern regex.)

Comment: You can use `"\">(?!\\s)"` to match for any instances of `">` followed by something other than whitespace for handling. Simple way would be running something like `.replaceAll("\">(?!\\s)", "\"> ")` to add whitespace after the hyperlinks before running your current code.

Comment: Good Morning! While this does seem to work, it now gives me the problem, that some words like "held" are now "hel d", which isn't very good. Isn't there an option, where it doesn't create a space, but still removes the URL tag?
Basically a bit like CTRL+F works, where it ignores spaces missing.

Comment: Wait... are the hyperlinks in the middle of the word sometimes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but what you need is to eliminate all the `<a>` tags from a given string, right? If that's the case all you needed to do was use a code like the following:

```
final String string = "<a href=\"http://www.example.com\">Sen";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a(.+?)>", Pattern.DOTALL);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
final String result = matcher.replaceAll("");

System.out.println(result); // prints "Sen"
```

Notice I didn't use the `replaceAll` from the String object, but from the Matcher object. This replaces all matches for the empty string "".

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve my problem at all.
My problem is, that it doesn't remove those tags, which are literally next to another word, without a space seperating it.

Comment: @Tomas Simons, but then why did you accept my answer? In my example I used a string just like in the example you gave and the result removes the tag and leaves only the remaining "Sen". I didn't understand how this does not solve your problem. Can you provide more examples?

Comment: It replaced them. Sadly some tags are still in the middle of the sentence, but it works. I've now actually decided to replace the endtag instead.